# Changing text color in Drupal Views admin pages

Tags: text, drupal-6, colors, view

Hope this is the right place to ask this question. I am new to the forum (and to Drupal!).
I am developing a site using Drupal. Am using Zenophile Midnight and have created a Zen sub Theme. This has three columns, each with a black background. 
I am trying to edit a View but when I open the views/edit node I find when I try to create a Filter the text does not show (presumably because it is black). How can I change this just for these pages and not for the whole site? I know the text is there as I can mark it by dragging over it.
Would be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you log in as the administrator of the site and select **Administer > Site Configuration > Administration Theme** there you can change the theme that is used for site administration. This does not affect the theme used by the site for the public view of the site.

You can select the default Garland theme for administration and your custom theme can be applied to the rest of the site.

Comment: Thanks, Vincent, for your rapid advice.
Brian